# Simultaneous video streaming to raspberry pi and GCS

Tags: pi-4, streaming-video, radio

I am working on a project in which I use a raspberry pi 4 on my drone to process the camera images and send some commands to pixhawk autopilot based on the information coming from image processing.

I need to stream the video simultaneously to my pi4 board (for image processing) and also to a ground station laptop that is about 2km far away(I need to monitor the drone behaviors to prevent crashes caused by failures in my algorithms and also to send confirmation to start some operations.).

I know that with FPV cameras I can get the live stream, but I don't know if it is possible to output the camera data to the raspberry pi board.

I have not bought the camera system yet so I am not limited to a specific camera or video transmitter. Also, I have searched for off-the-shelf modules to do this for me, but I could not find anything helpful, so any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Surely this question is better-suited for your camera manufacturer? Have you tried that approach?

Comment: dear @Seamus since the transmission system was unknown, I have not selected the camera yet and I want to buy a camera suitable for the transmission system.